# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, windows-8

I've installed Windows on half of my hard disk space. Only one partition. I would like to install Ubuntu into my free disk space. The question:

In Ubuntu Installer, when I choose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows", what's the next step: installer will realocate my NTFS partition, ignoring my free space or it will install Ubuntu into my free disk space, automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Installer has an inbuilt partitioner that will let you use a *slider* to easily make space for ubuntu. So there is no need to manually create partition tables. It will certainly detect free space but you will have to chose how much space you want to allocate to Ubuntu by dragging the slider.

More on this can be read here on dual boot: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Alternatively, you can shrink your windows partition from inside windows also to make room for ubuntu. Read more details here on the Ubuntu help site : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions

Considering that you use windows 8, you will likely find few resources to help you. but these ways should work just fine.

Cheers